# How to change StatusBar background on desktop or tablet?

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

How can I change StatusBar background on desktop or tablet? I can do that on phone but not on other form-factors. I've seen it in new Todoist app for Windows 10. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StatusBar` does not available for Desktop and Tablet. I guess you meant `TitleBar`:

```
var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.BackgroundColor = new Color() { A = 255, R = 54, G = 60, B = 116 };
titleBar.ForegroundColor = new Color() { A = 255, R = 232, G = 211, B = 162 };
titleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = new Color() { A = 255, R = 135, G = 141, B = 199 };
titleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = new Color() { A = 255, R = 232, G = 211, B = 162 };
```

More details look at [the sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar)

Also look at this [cool sample](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/easily-manage-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-apps/)